# Outputting a SESSION following user input - protect against xss

Tags: php, xss

I have this code to echo out a username of a user that has just logged in:

```
echo $_SESSION['user']['username']."
```

Would I be right in thinking that if I change my code to:

```
echo htmlspecialchars $_SESSION['user']['username']."
```

i am protecting myself from low level XSS atleast?

Comment: Why are you allowing XSS-able characters into your usernames in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function htmlspecialchars does not encode single quotation(') by default, if your user name echo in an html attribute or inside javascript, there would be XSS!

For example:

```
<script>
name='$YOUR_NAME_HERE$';
</script>
```

We can set the user name to ';alert('xss');//
So the browser will generate the html content like this

```
<script>
name='';alert('xss');//';
</script>
```

And my advice to you is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 3):

That depends on where you output the username. If it's between html tags, yes. If it's in an html attribute, it depends on the attribute. See the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet.